# Why I can't add another class inside my element with bootstrap class form-control? if I add but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to insert class using `element.classList.add("anyClass");` it does not work, if it had form-control bootstrap class as I have given inside code, if I use `remove` instead of `add` and type `element.classList.remove("form-control");` it works fine

```js
function validation() {
  var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name");
  // var last_name=document.getElementById("last_name");
  // var address=document.getElementById("address");
  // var phone_no=document.getElementById("phone_no");
  // var email=document.getElementById("email");

  if (first_name.value === "") {
    first_name.classList.add("add_border_left");
    first_name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.add_border_left {
  border-left: #d9534f 4px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for="">First Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" onkeydown="clear_first_name();" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="first_name" autofocus>
  <!-- <label  id="valid_first_name" for="">Please Enter Valid First Name</label> -->
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button type="submit" style=" margin-top: 30px; letter-spacing: 2px;" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how is `validation` called?

Comment: you never call validation function in your form. That's why you never see the red border...

Comment: i have another element called form , inside which validation(); function is being called on submit , but the problem is when i validate my form and fields or empty i want my text field to show border on left side in red color and form should not be submitted, as I have used "if" to check condition value is empty then run that block , but inside that block, first_name.focus(); is working fine, but when i try to add new class using first_name.classList.Add("anyClass"); it wont be add because i already have form-control class in element , if i use classList and add class then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please also mention clear_first_name() method.

For now, I just place validation() method on replacing of that and class is added.

```js
function validation()
{
    var first_name=document.getElementById("first_name");
    // var last_name=document.getElementById("last_name");
    // var address=document.getElementById("address");
    // var phone_no=document.getElementById("phone_no");
    // var email=document.getElementById("email");
console.log(first_name.value)

   
    if(first_name.value === "")
    {
        first_name.classList.add("add_border_left");
        first_name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

```css
.add_border_left
{
   border-left: #d9534f 4px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                        <label for="">First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" onkeydown="validation();" autocomplete="off"  type="text"
                            id="first_name" autofocus>
                        <!-- <label  id="valid_first_name" for="">Please Enter Valid First Name</label> -->
                    </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" style=" margin-top: 30px; letter-spacing: 2px;"
                         class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: for you information, I have main element called form inside that I am calling function validation onsubmit, and the function onkeydown work is different and that is working fine.

Comment: i have another element called form , inside which validation(); function is being called on submit , but the problem is when i validate my form and fields or empty i want my text field to show border on left side in red color and form should not be submitted, as I have used "if" to check condition value is empty then run that block , but inside that block, first_name.focus(); is working fine, but when i try to add new class using first_name.classList.Add("anyClass"); it wont be add because i already have form-control class in element , if i use classList and add class then it is working fine.